# How to write text diagonally on a image using XSL FO

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, document, xsl-fo

I have a text written on a certificate document which is an image, but I am trying to write the text diagonally on the image. I am unable to change it even after changing the reference orientation of the container within which the text is present.

```
<xsl:template match="graphicBack">
        <fo:block absolute-position="absolute">
            <fo:block-container position="absolute">
                <fo:external-graphic xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" scaling="uniform" content-width="210mm" content-height="296.99mm">
                    <xsl:attribute name="src" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                        <xsl:value-of select="var" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </fo:external-graphic>
            </fo:block-container>
            <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" left="20mm" top="200mm">
                <fo:block color="#CC6133" font-family="Courier" font-style="normal" display-align="center" font-size="300px">
             COPY
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Where did you put the `fo:reference-orientation="45"` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AH Formatter, then you can use `axf:transform` and `axf:transform-origin` (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#transformation) to rotate the block to an arbitrary angle.

See the 'Block transformation' example in the "XSL-FO Samples Collection" at https://www.antennahouse.com/xsl-fo-samples.

Comment: The PO is working with *formatting output* (fo), not with *AH formatter* (axf).

Comment: AH Formatter implements XSL-FO, arguably more so than any other formatter: https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf66/ahf-fo11.html. Properties with the `axf` prefix are extensions beyond what's in the XSL 1.1 Recommendation. Rotating text is not in XSL 1.1, but it did get one line in the XSL 2.0 Requirements document: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20-req/#N67162

Comment: I am using a document management system and it does not allow axf:transform commands. would there be any other way to diagonally align the text

Comment: Generate SVG for the rotated text as an `fo:instream-foreign-object`.

Comment: I just found that FOP has an `fox:transform` property to do much the same thing. See https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.4/extensions.html#transform.

Comment: Tony Graham's solutions are the ones I'd go for. Both work great.